# How do I replace a user entered sentence with a user entered word. str object not callable

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

```
sentence = input ('Please enter a sentce: ')
change = input ('What word do you want to change: ')
replace = input ('What do you want to replace it with: ')
n_s = replace(change,replace)
print (n_s)
```

I've got this but when I run it it says

```
n_s = replace(change,replace) TypeError:'str' object is not callable
```

Comment: Did you mean `sentence.replace(...)`. The error is telling you that `replace` is just a `str`, which it is because you defined it on line `3`.

Answer (score 2):

You want: `n_s = sentence.replace(change, replace)`.  It is giving you a type error because your variable named `replace` is a string and you are trying to call it like a method.

Answer (score 1):

```
sentence = input ('Please enter a sentce: ')
change = input ('What word do you want to change: ')
replace = input ('What do you want to replace it with: ')
n_s = sentence.replace(change,replace)
print(n_s)

#output:
Please enter a sentce: hello world bye
What word do you want to change: bye
What do you want to replace it with: bye-bye
hello world bye-bye
```

The method replace() returns a copy of the string in which the occurrences of old have been replaced with new, optionally restricting the number of replacements to max.

Syntax: `str.replace(old, new[, max])`

- old − This is old substring to be replaced.
- new − This is new substring, which would replace old substring.
- max − If this optional argument max is given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the corrected code, for python 3.  Notice that the syntax for the last line before the print statement is n_s = sentence.replace(change,replace)

```
sentence = input ('Please enter a sentce: ')
change = input ('What word do you want to change: ')
replace = input ('What do you want to replace it with: ')
n_s = sentence.replace(change,replace)
print (n_s)
```